# How to implement: two views coordinating same selection in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, selection, rcp

I have multiple views in an eclipse RCP application:

1) map view with push pin icons
2) list view of all push pins
3) a view displaying the push pin properties

I also have a model object with a get/setActivePushPin acessor methods.

How do I properly coordinate the push pin selection?

When I select a push pin on either the map or list view, the active push pin should change and the other view should be notified.

I realize each view needs to have a ISelectionListener, but it seems that the listeners should be hooking into a common ISelectionProvider specifically for push pin selection events rather than explicitly hooking into a particular view.

Answer (score 3):

This developerWorks article "[Make your Eclipse applications richer with view linking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/?ca=dgr-lnxw03EclipseGUIviews)" describes almost exactly your example. It is especially good as it describes two 'pardigms' to the same problem -

- selection provider-selection listener paradigm
- property change listener paradigm

A more detailed article on how the selection service works comes from this eclipse.org article: "[Eclipse Workbench: Using the Selection Service](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html)".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use global Selection Service, which coordinates selection for entire workbench. See article describing "Selection Service" and its usage: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html